# Only fullscreen activities can request orientation (START APP)

Tags: java, android

After I update the phone I used to try the application. I'm starting to get this error. I have updated android studio, but it has not improved. what can I do ?

```
--------- beginning of crash
06-18 23:55:52.461 18698-18698/com.dogi.dogi.freemusicdownload E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dogi.dogi.freemusicdownload, PID: 18698
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.dogi.dogi.freemusicdownload/com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities.OverlayActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3790)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3830)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3038)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1966)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1904)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setRequestedOrientation(IActivityManager.java:6194)
    at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:5831)
    at com.startapp.android.publish.common.commonUtils.b.a(StartAppSDK:201)
    at com.startapp.android.publish.common.commonUtils.s.a(StartAppSDK:211)
    at com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities.OverlayActivity.onResume(StartAppSDK:126)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1361)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7352)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3830) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3038) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

[MANIFEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBL3E.png)
[MANIFEST 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWIQ2.png)

Comment: Can you share Activity declarition in manifest.xml?

Comment: Are you using AdMob? Or FirebaseAds?

Comment: If so you may just need to update your firebase to the latest. Currently it is at:
    
implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1

Comment: no I m not using firebaseads. I m using startapp

Comment: I m edit my manifest.. thanks..